# Font-Size by Userselection

Tags: react-native

I currently run into some trouble. Maybe someone has a propper soultion. I want to give the user (in a seprate screen) a slider to change the font-size of the App.

I story Currently the value of the slider in the async-storage to get the value in my styles from the storage. The problem is, that the asyncstorage is loaded after the stylesheets. Does anyone has made such a function an could give me please a hint.

Comment: Have your slider apply a specific class name or `data-*` attribute on your page's `<body>` tag, then style that through your CSS.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly question is about react-native. react-native doesn't use default HTML tags.

Comment: @Marq please give [mcve] to show what you have tried so far so we can help.

Comment: here is the minimal example:

https://pastebin.com/VVjf83XG